# Difference between accessing fragments by Tag or Id

Tags: android, android-fragments

I know I can create a fragment and add it via Tag or Id. Is it optional to use either one? Is there any kind of reason why I should use one over the other?

```
model = new ModelFragment();

//tag
getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().add(model, "tag").commit();
//id
getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().add( 4, model).commit();
```

Comment: those were my baby steps, long live almighty Android! :)

Answer (score 5):

IDs are used for static fragments, fragments whose state you don't want to modify during the activity life cycle.

To dynamically add a fragment use tags :

```
android.app.FragmentTransaction ft = getFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
    ft.replace(R.id.fragment_container, fragment, TAG);
    ft.commit();
```

To get the fragment somewhere in code, use something like:

```
if(getFragmentManager().findFragmentByTag(TAG)!=null){
      ft.remove(getFragmentManager().findFragmentByTag(TAG));
      ft.commit();  
 }
```

Comment: Could you provide a link to the Android Documentation where they state this?

Answer (score 1):

I believe you can only add an `id` to a `Fragment` if it is a static `Fragment` (i.e. via xml). If you want to dynamically add `Fragments` via `FragmentTransaction` the third parameter of `add()` is a `String` for the tag. Giving a tag is optional, but recommended so you can get a hold of the `Fragment` later on.

On the id case you are showing, the first parameter of `add()` is the layout id of the container you want to add the `Fragment` to, not the id for the `Fragment` itself.

Answer (score 1):

IDs are used to identify the container this fragment will be placed into. [Taken from documentation](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/FragmentTransaction.html#add%28int,%20android.app.Fragment,%20java.lang.String%29):
*`containerViewId`  Optional identifier of the container this fragment is to be placed in. If 0, it will not be placed in a container.*
Using this id, you can retrieve the fragment later on with `findFragmentById` - see below.

Tags are a label used by fragment manager to later identify and retrieve a fragment. By using a tag, a fragment can be identified no matter what container holds that fragment.

Ids and tags can be used at the same time or separatelly. `FragmentManager` can identify a fragment by [both id](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/FragmentManager.html#findFragmentById%28int%29) and [tag](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/FragmentManager.html#findFragmentByTag%28java.lang.String%29).

Answer (score 0):

> I believe you can only add an id to a Fragment if it is a static Fragment (i.e. via xml)

I think it's an incorrect statement as I'm certain You can write something like:

```
mCoordinatorLayout.id = R.id.myview // or View.generateViewId() giving it whatever Id that You can retrieve later on typing: mCoordinatorLayout.id
```

So You can set the ID dynamically.

I think that TAG's work a bit differently (safer) and was introduced to avoid some bugs (I encountered) when You remove and add View Object's programmatically OR EVEN BEFORE COMPILING !
Let's say You write some code assigning a Button ID 'viewid'
Since now 'viewid' stays as an entry in R.id file and the entry is linked to the Button having assigned 'under the hood' it's Object number.
Than You remove code declaring the Button (but the 'viewid' is still there referencing to now nonexistent Object ! Probably it's not a big problem if You just leave the rubbish in the R.id file not using the same name again before compiling as most likely the link to nonexistent object would be cleared off during the next compilation)
But...
Now (before next compiling) create for an instance a FloatingActionButton (which is a different Object) and than assign it same named ID: 'viewid'.
BUG ! It's still referencing nonexistent Object (the already removed from code Button).
If it's nonexistent that's not the worse - it will give an error during compilation.
But imagine You have added another similar View, it compiles fine, but leads to unexpected behaviour referencing all the time wrong object !
I experienced that and it wasted me plenty of time...

It took me a lot to find out what was the problem and how to sort it out (clean project->rebuild project->clear caches and restart AS - not sure if all the steps was required, but it helps).

R.id file is just a list of ID's and it can also contain ID's for future purposes (or accidentally left rubbish).
Compiler must swap the alphanumeric representation of the ID's on numbers numbering View Objects as they go (1,2,3...). Than You can run on it

```
findViewById(whatever_id) // where 'whatever_id' under the hood really is an Object number
```

I guess there is some similar issue happening on run time and that's the reason of later on introducing TAG (which maybe stays in memory as an alphanumeric entry instead of just a number being more unambiguous ??) which runs extra check mechanisms to avoid such of bugs.
I think that ID may be working faster as under the hood it's operating on just a simple number with no fancy checks and that's why Android developers did not deprecated it (perhaps just yet only as it is deeply sitting in Android core since it's first revisions, but it may be a matter of time ??).

BTW
I've reported that the bug to AS, but they took no action about it maybe because I got some noobish rating so please let them know if You can as it is a serious bug.